# how can i map lat and lng to geo_point type in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation, nest

Im using elasticsearch 7 and nest 6.7 .

I have index that has any type like coordinate .

in any way im mapping geo_type i have problem .

```
 client.CreateIndex("staging2", c => c.Mappings(m => m.Map<VenueIndex>(mm => mm.AutoMap())));
```

this is my nest code and this is som part of my poko class :

```
     public object Promotion { get; set; }
    public object Checkin { get; set; }
    public Featured Featured { get; set; }
    public int BinaryType { get; set; }
    public List<WorkingHour> WorkingHours { get; set; }
    [GeoPoint(Name = "location", IgnoreMalformed = true)]
    public Geoloc _geoloc { get; set; }
    public string Neighbourhood { get; set; }
    public List<int> MealTimes { get; set; }
    public string objectID { get; set; }

    public class Geoloc
{

    [Number(NumberType.Double, Name = "lat")]
    public double lat { get; set; }
    [Number(NumberType.Double, Name = "lon")]
    public double lon { get; set; }
}
```

in this way GeoLoc type is float

other way when i user post man still have this problem .

my json object is somthing like this :

```
{
  "isClubMember": false,
 "rating": 0.0,
 "binaryType": 2,
 "location": {
 "lat":"32.11",
 "lon":"-34.22"
 },
   "neighbourhood": "شهرک والفجر,امیر آباد",
   "mealTimes": [],
   "objectID": "188dc91e-8088-4099-9eb8-00aa73653192"}
```

where is my mistake ?

Comment: can u add the mapping?

Comment: @jaspreetchahal u mean postman mapping ?

Comment: mapping of the index.

Comment: If I am correct your issue is that "location" is getting created with type float instead of geo_point. ?

Comment: @jaspreetchahal yes , this is my problem

Comment: I used your model and tried to create index, field is getting created correctly -"location" : {  "type" : "geo_point",  "ignore_malformed" : true  },

Comment: @jaspreetchahal can you post it as answer . with correct indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model:

```
    public class TestClass
    {
        public object Promotion { get; set; }
        public object Checkin { get; set; }
        [GeoPoint(Name = "location", IgnoreMalformed = true)]
        public Geoloc _geoloc { get; set; }
        public string Neighbourhood { get; set; }
        public List<int> MealTimes { get; set; }
        public string objectID { get; set; }
    }
    public class Geoloc
    {
        [Number(NumberType.Double, Name = "lat")]
        public double lat { get; set; }
        [Number(NumberType.Double, Name = "lon")]
        public double lon { get; set; }
    }
```

Code to create mapping using NEST

```
var url = "http://localhost:9200";
            var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(url));
            EsClient = new ElasticClient(settings);

            if (!EsClient.IndexExists("gcheck").Exists)
            {
                var resp = EsClient.CreateIndex("gcheck", c => c
                 .Map<TestClass>(mp => mp
                 .Properties(
                     ps => ps
                 ).AutoMap()
                ));
            }
```

Output mapping:

```
 "gcheck" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "binaryType" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "checkin" : {
          "type" : "object"
        },
        "isClubMember" : {
          "type" : "boolean"
        },
        "location" : {
          "type" : "geo_point",
          "ignore_malformed" : true
        },
        "mealTimes" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "neighbourhood" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "objectID" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "promotion" : {
          "type" : "object"
        },
        "rating" : {
          "type" : "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: .Map<VenueIndex>(mp => mp
                 .Properties(
                     ps => ps
                 ).AutoMap() i have error in this block . ('CreateIndexDescriptor' does not contain a definition for 'Map')

Comment: I am using Nest 7.0.  Can u try this syntax var createIndexResponse = _client.CreateIndex("myindex", c => c     .Mappings(ms => ms         .Map<Document>(m => m             .AutoMap<Company>()              .AutoMap(typeof(Employee))          )     ) );  This is for NEST 6.x